# Is Hala travel company acting on behalf of the Egyptian government?

Tags: 2023-israel-hamas-war, gaza, egypt

Hala travel company, belonging to Ibrahim al-Argany, is taking care of transporting Palestinians from Gaza, [charging rather exorbitant fees](https://www.memri.org/reports/lebanese-daily-al-akhbar-egyptian-regime-profiteering-gaza-war-and-gazans-suffering-%E2%80%93):

> Abu Muhammad, a Palestinian travel agent who works with the Hala travel agency, says that the brokerage fees for traveling with the [Hala] company have changed during the course of the war. Whereas at the beginning of the war they were as high as $10,000 per person, in the last few months they gradually dropped, and last month they were $5,000 for a person over 12 and $500-$2,500 per child, depending on the number of people in the family. For Palestinians with Egyptian citizenship, the price is $1,200-$1,600. The agent explains that the price dropped because, in the beginning [of the war], the people who paid to leave the Strip were merchants and businesspeople, whereas [today] there are few of them left. The demand also fell because of the high prices, so prices were lowered in order to maximize the number of travelers and thus the profits.

[Lebanese Al-Akhbar (cited above) refers to this situation as corruption](https://www.memri.org/reports/lebanese-daily-al-akhbar-egyptian-regime-profiteering-gaza-war-and-gazans-suffering-%E2%80%93):

> Egyptian Regime Profiteering From Gaza War And Gazans' Suffering – Imposing High Taxes And Taking Bribes At Gaza Border Crossings

whereas [Egyptian Mada Masr, although confirming the information on the fees, seems to treat Argany as somewhat of a lifesaving line for the stranded Palestinians](https://www.madamasr.com/en/2024/02/13/feature/politics/the-argany-peninsula/):

> Amid this formal stalemate, people and aid still pass through the crossing. And how it is done is an open secret.
>
> Behind the scenes stands a solitary figure, in whom business, power and international relations intersect, a figure who, in less than a decade, has transformed from a fugitive of justice to a tribal battalion leader, a partner in the Egyptian military in its war on terrorism and one of Egypt’s most influential businessmen.
>
> The precipitous rise of Ibrahim al-Argany, the figure behind it all, has raised many questions in recent years that have only grown sharper as the aggression’s violence mounted. Now, everything and everyone that passes into or out of Gaza does so almost exclusively through Argany’s companies and his network of connections.

Were Agrany and his company given official monopoly on transporting people and goods across the Egypt-Gaza border by Egyptian authorities, or is this some kind of mafia/local militia/warlord that Egypt is unable to control? ([Some media openly refer to Agrany as *militia businessman*.](https://www.africaintelligence.com/north-africa/2023/09/25/the-rise-of-militia-businessman-arjani,110056895-ge0))

Comment: It would seem that Ibrahim al-Argany is too powerful and too useful an ally for the Egyptian government to take action against him. That information pretty much seems to be in the articles you cite. The precise legal status of the transportation and how exactly he gets around Egyptian law and authorities might merit a more detailed answer.